# AWS running Glue charges "USE1-GlueInteractiveSession-DPU-Hour" - 306.719 DPU-Hour no idea how to stop?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I was testing out sending queries redshift both through jobs and from a notebook. Nothing crazy, just select statments (which I believe were all limited in rows) and create table statements. I noticed that I suddenly had a large ($100) spike in charges, with cost explorer I was able to see that what was costing was "USE1-GlueInteractiveSession-DPU-Hour" and in billing I can see Ive been charged for

> $0.44 per Data Processing Unit-Hour for AWS Glue interactive sessions
> and job notebooks
> 306.719 DPU-Hour

While I did use a notebook I have no idea why it would consume that much data processing? Does this mean I was charged that much just for having the notebook active? Trying to understand how these charges happened so I can avoid them/stop them. My total job run DPU usage is only 16 hours, so not sure how something would rack up 300 hours?

Comment: An interactive session has multiple workers -- the default notebook has 5 workers. I believe these will run as long as the notebook's kernel is running. As a result, we've disabled sessions organization-wide (a SCP that denies `glue:CreateSession`), and use the AWS-provided Docker images: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html#develop-local-docker-image